# Yup validation to check if object with dynamic keys is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have an object with dynamic keys, so it's difficult to use

```
Yup.object().shape({name: Yup.string().required()})
```

how do I validate when the key "name" is dynamic

Comment: How can you validate it if you don't know what shape it should be?

Comment: I know the shape the only thing dynamic is the keys of the object

Comment: Which means you don't know the shape? Surely? Would you please tell us the shape?